# My for loop in python is giving me back 2 loops instead of one

Tags: python, list, loops

So I have a function thats this:

```
def get_hour_from_line(line_string):
# This function takes the line as a string for input and
# returns the hour as an integer

infile = open(line_string,"r")

data = infile.read()

new_lst = data.split(",")


for i in new_lst:
    data = i.split()



    print(data)
```

The output I get is:

```
['NULL', '9/12/14', '22:50']
['6763'] #continues down for a long time
```

I need to assign a variable, hours, to the 2nd item in the first list. However if I index [-1] or [2:3] I still end up with the [
'6763'] or a []. Is there a way to delete that second list or iterate over it??

Comment: try `data = new_lst[0].split()`, this will give you the first list.

Comment: Yeah that works to get the first list but then it justs prints that one out for the range of the new_lst. How would I iterate to the next line??

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean. Provide an example.

Comment: you don't need a for loop just `data = new_lst[0].split();print(data[0])` would be fine.

Comment: Well i have what I want now it looks like this for i in new_lst:

        i = new_lst[1].split(',')
        hours = i[0]


        print(hours) But it only gives me the time for the first line. I need to step through all the other lines in the code though.

Comment: ohhhh yeah this is a table of data. The output is only for one of the lines in the data, there are like 50 more lines with different values i need to loop through.